# Фактическая роль репозитория в Clean Architecture

Tags: java, android, архитектура

Задался вопросом: а кем выступает репозиторий для `Domain` слоя. Правильно ли я понимаю, что репозиторий — просто мост, между логикой и системно-зависимой частью? Например, если репозитрий берет данные из SQLite БД, он читает данные из Data-слоя, потому что только он знает, как работать конкретно с этой БД. Выходит, репозиторий просто преобразует объекты типа `AccountRecord` в `Account` (добавляя различные функции как сортировка, фильтрация и прочее)?

---

Вопрос: какая фактическая роль репозитория и какова его задача для `Domain` слоя?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Репозитрий — является интерфейсом доступа к системно-зависимой части. Этим интерфейсом владеет слой с бизнес-логикой, через которую и производит работу с данными. Этим достигается принцип независимости от деталей.